# AC disconnect vs. Hot tub disconnect?

Tags: electrical-panel, subpanel, hot-tub

I've finished the run from my Main to my new subpanel. The subpanel is not within the required 25' of my hot tub, I have a 50 amp GFCI installed in the subpanel which is dedicated to the hot tub. I was planning on installing a hot tub disconnect closer to the hot tub. In looking at hot tub disconnects which include breaker (50 amp), pricing is pushing $100. I then saw a 60 amp AC pull disconnect ($25), about the only thing I see different (aside from the breaker) is an AC disconnect is a 3 wire system vs. 4. The AC disconnect doesn't have a ground it seems.

My question:
Since the disconnect is downstream of the 50 amp GFCI, could I use the 60 amp A/C pull disconnect, add a grounding bar, and run 4 wires?

If not, what's the most cost-effective solution?

Answer (score 2):

All GFCIs are able to protect additional parts of a circuit, provided that circuit is attached to their "Load" terminals.   When you install a 240V GFCI *breaker* that's the only way to use it lol.

When an outlet is protected by a GFCI elsewhere, a second GFCI is redundant and pointless.

So that answers your question about whether you need a second GFCI - no you don't, and it's a waste of money if you do.  Code doesn't even require this.

---

Now we get into a "name game".  You can get disconnects (really: mini 2-space subpanels) that have a GFCI breaker pre-installed, and the trade name for those is "hot tub disconnect".  You don't need that.   A regular disconnect will do.

I myself would go a little more upscale than a "pullout disconnect" because if their contacts get hot, they'll melt the plastic handle.  I prefer either the lever kind, or simply the "2-space subpanel" kind with a plain breaker.  Neither of which is terribly expensive.

Neutral doesn't go through the breaker or switch on these. If they don't provide separate neutral and ground lugs that are isolated, either buy an accessory ground bar ($5-6) or just splice the neutral wires to each other e.g. via an ILSCO "Mac Block Connector", which takes two #6 wires.

Since *absolutely everyone who looks* will ask "Where's the GFCI?????", you must apply a "GFCI Protected" label to the disconnect.  I say "must" because this is a Code requirement.  110.3(B) and instructions 8(C).

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated.